# Can one reference id directly in kotlin?My small program can't seem to run

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Hi im new in android and i read that i can directly reference id from activity_main to mainAcctivity.kt without using findviewbyid.When i do that i get an error but my ids are correct:
This is the error Unresolved reference: button and Unresolved reference: textView
This is my code

````
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

// get reference to button
                //val btnClickMe = findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
                //val myTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
                var timesClicked = 0
// set on-click listener
        button.setOnClickListener {
            timesClicked += 1
            textView.text = timesClicked.toString()
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Hello Don.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }
}```
Please help out,i tried to import android.widget.button and textView that option is not available but when i hardcode the text appears inactive.
````

Comment: You need to apply viewbinding. Please check [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Answer (score 0):

- You can make use of [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) to reduce the use of `findViewById`. You can find an example [here](https://androideveryday.com/2018/11/08/findviewbyid-in-kotlin/).
- You can go through this [blog](https://proandroiddev.com/hello-viewbinding-goodbye-findviewbyid-edca92b397c) to have more insight on how to use *ViewBinding*.
- For the above code, you can resolve the issue using the code below:

```
    val myTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    val btnClickMe = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
```

Comment: Yeah that works i wanted to use the id directly since i wanted to optimize the code,so i tried button.setOnClickListener but that seems not to work

Comment: Actually ViewBinding is meant to accomplish this. You can directly use buttons with their ID just like this `button.setOnClickListener` using this feature.

Comment: You can refer to the blog which I have answered above to know how to use it.

Comment: did you configure your project a a kotlin project? or you just created a kotlin file in a java project?

Comment: Yes its a kotlin project